# What if the batteries aren't equal to each other but are parallel?

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis

As seen at the top, I've uploaded a circuit which its batteries are equal. So, we can tell that E1 = E2 = E3, because they are parallel. If so, what if they aren't equal to each other but even they are parallel? Here's a circuit to specify what I mean. Hope you get it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frnzfqm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

or

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAu0P3m.png)</sup>

Comment: They will get hot, and the one with the highest voltage will discharge into the others until they reach equilibrium.

Comment: @Colin__s How? can you give an example?

Comment: Ohms law: the through a resistor = V/R and if R is zero then current  = infinity.

Comment: @Andyaka The question is not about the resistance. I just didn't add the resistances.

Comment: @Goendo: Yes it is. You just haven't realised it yet.

Comment: @Transistor It isn't. I'm asking what to do when there are the batteries which are in parallel and not equal to each other.

Comment: Oh yes it is!!!!

Comment: "what to do"? You could watch the wires interconnecting them melt. That's usually of some interest to some noobs.

Comment: What if you put a 0 volt power source across a 12 volt battery from a car?

Comment: @Andyaka So? what you mean

Comment: A 0 volt power source produces no power but has an impedance of zero ohms.

Comment: #2 is worse than a short circuit because you are apply reverse voltage.  Internal resistance if ~5 ohms on 9V battery implies current = 18V/(5+2.5) = 2.4A and I^2R of self heating ..boom

Answer (score 5):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV7qoI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuit for parallel batteries.*

Real batteries have internal resistance.

If you parallel a 9, 6 and 8 V battery as shown the voltage difference between the negative and positive rails will be somewhere between 6 and 9 V depending on the value of each of the internal resistances. If, for example, it settled down at 7.5 V then E1 and E2 would be discharged and E2 would be charged.

How long the batteries could tolerate this depends on their chemistry, internal resistance, their rating and, perhaps, the local cooling.

If your batteries are capable of very high currents and have low internal resistance (e.g., car or truck batteries) then hundreds of amps may flow and explosion may result.

Answer (score 0):

Your batteries are voltage sources in series with some resistance. Making your circuit really

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbldqL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, there is a 3 V drop over whatever R1 + R2 is. The sum of R1 and R2 will be fairly small, which means the current will be fairly high, this is where the heat comes from.